# Test for specific InnerException in Try/Catch

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a TCP client/server app using Stream.Read (with blocking I/O) inside my client handler function.  When I shutdown my server, I get an IO exception {"Unable to read data from the transport connection: A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall."}, which is to be expected.
I'm using a Try/Catch around the Stream.Read and would like to test for this specific exception and ignore it, but still handle any other exceptions.

My first thought was to have a specific Catch for the SocketException Interrupt error followed by a more general Catch for anything else.  That failed to Catch anything because the exception thrown is NOT a SocketException: the SocketException is the InnerException of the IO exception.

Here's some pseudo-code for what I'd like to do:

```
Try
    Dim RawDataResp(255) As Byte
    Dim RawRespLen As Integer
    RawRespLen = Stream.Read(RawDataResp, 0, RawDataResp.Length)
    ' do some stuff with my data ...
Catch ex As Exception
    If ex.InnerException IsNot Nothing AndAlso

' The next line gives: 'SocketErrorCode' is not a member of 'Exception'.
        ex.InnerException.SocketErrorCode = SocketError.Interrupted Then

            print("Socket read interrupted; expected on Server shutdown")
    Else
        ' Handle any other exceptions here...
    End If
End Try
```

It seems like I should be able to cast ex to a SocketException (maybe using GetType...) in order to reference SocketErrorCode, but I just can't seem to find the right syntax.
Thanks for any help

Comment: The proper way to filter exceptions based on anything other than direct type is to use a `When` clause on the `Catch` statement.  See my answer below.

Comment: Too much help, do keep in mind that you can use more than one Catch statement.  The first one should be `As ObjectDisposedException`, the one that unambiguously tells you that the socket got closed.  You don't care about the InnerException, just do nothing since you expect it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `When` clause on a `Catch` statement for filtering.  It is like using an `If` within the `Catch` block except that it allows other `Catch` statements to be tested if the condition is `False`.  Without actually having tested it, I think that this should work:

```
Try
    '...
Catch ex As Exception When TryCast(ex.InnerException, SocketException) IsNot Nothing
    'Process any exception where the inner exception is type SocketException.
Catch ex As Exception
    'Process all other exceptions.
End Try
```

You can get even more specific with the filter if you want, e.g.

```
Try
    '...
Catch ex As Exception When TryCast(ex.InnerException, SocketException)?.SocketErrorCode = SocketError.Interrupted
    'Process any exception where the inner exception is type SocketException and the error code is Interrupted.
Catch ex As Exception
    'Process all other exceptions.
End Try
```

Note the user of null propagation, i.e. the `?.` operator, so that no `NullReferenceException` will be thrown if there is no inner exception or it's not the specified type.  Also note that the second `Catch` block is optional and you can simply allow all other exceptions to go unhandled at this level.

Not surprisingly, [the documentation for exception handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/try-catch-finally-statement) in VB includes explanation and examples of the use of `When` with `Catch`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that the `InnerException` is going to be a `SocketException` (and hence have the `SocketErrorCode` property), you could change its type:

```
Try
    Dim RawDataResp(255) As Byte
    Dim RawRespLen As Integer
    RawRespLen = Stream.Read(RawDataResp, 0, RawDataResp.Length)
    ' do some stuff with my data ...
Catch ex As Exception
Dim innerException as SocketException = TryCast(ex.InnerException, SocketException)
        If innerException IsNot Nothing AndAlso innerException.SocketErrorCode = SocketError.Interrupted Then

            print("Socket read interrupted; expected on Server shutdown")
    Else
        ' Handle any other exceptions here...
    End If
End Try
```

I'm eager to see if any VB.NET pro can point towards a safer and more elegant solution.

Comment: My only comment would be to use TryCast rather than Cast.  Dim innerException as SocketException = TryCast(ex.InnerException, SocketException).  Then If innerException IsNot Nothing Blah blah.....

Comment: @Hursey That's a good one. I went for CType 'cause TryCast returns Nothing if the conversion is unsuccessful, tho, so he'll probably have to check for that. By trying to change the type directly, the failure case would be handled by the "Handle any other exceptions here..." part commented by the OP.
But in my approach, the attempt to access SocketErrorCode on Nothing might mess the exception handling by throwing a FieldAccessException, so it's debatible.

Comment: that is exactly my point.  If it can't be converted to a SocketException either because it's empty or a different type it returns Nothing so it does the type check and cast in one step

Comment: (I meant InvalidCastException, not FieldAccessException.)

Comment: @Hursey Oh, wait, I'm dumb, I was totally missing the step saving part. Thanks for noticing, I'll edit the answer later.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for; I've updated my code per @Hursey's first comment; was surprised I couldn't find this topic by searching SO; thanks to you both.

Comment: The more correct way to write `ex.InnerException IsNot Nothing AndAlso CType(ex.InnerException, SocketException).SocketErrorCode = SocketError.Interrupted` in recent versions of VB is `TryCast(ex.InnerException, SocketException)?.SocketErrorCode = SocketError.Interrupted`.